# By.cssSelector() cannot find element on a radio button - what's missing here?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Any thought what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my HTML code where I'm trying to do same thing but I'm getting element not found:

```
<div class="cell option">
<div class="form chk left">
<input id="check_returndate" type="radio" checked="" value="1" name="return"/>
<label for="check_returndate">Round trip</label>
</div>
<div class="form chk left">
<input id="check_oneway" type="radio" value="0" name="return"/>
<label for="check_oneway">One way</label>
</div>
</div>
```

And, here is my java code that I'm using:

```
driver.get("http://flight.ca/");

//accessing radio button

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='check_oneway'][value='0'] [type='radio']")).click();
```

Error I'm seeing is :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"input[id='check_oneway'][value='0']
>   [type='radio']"}
>       Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set context of the driver to the frame where the element is.
Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://flight.ca");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#check_oneway")).click();
```

Comment: This approach worked! But curious to know why are we using switchTo() here? I actually wanted to what would indicate that I need to set context to the frame. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A frame is a web page inside a web page. To know if your element is inside a frame, you need to inspect the DOM, and check if it's inside a <iframe> or <frame>.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `driver.findElement(By.id("check_oneway"))`

For CSS selector use `By.cssSelector("input[id='check_oneway'][value='0'][type='radio']")`

You have space between the value and type filter that is why your selector not working.

Comment: I agree, just go by the id.  That is supposed to be unique.  If you were to use value, then you won't find the radio button if the value happens to be 1.

Comment: Sorry even I have tried after removing the space and also By.id but still gives same error. But second below approach worked.

Comment: Do you have iFrames in your html?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=check_oneway][value=0][type=radio]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("check_returndate")).click();
```